# joining pandas dataframes by string prefix

Tags: python, pandas, join, string-matching

I am looking for an efficient way to perform the following join on two pandas.DataFrames:

The first one contains in column `A` strings like:

```
A  ....

Spam|One
Spam|Two
Ham
Eggs
```

The second one is a reference table with string keys as the index and a text description:

```
index      description
Spam       "..."
Ham        "..." 
Eggs       "...."
BakedBeans "...."
```

Each key in the index can be a prefix to a string in `A`.  Now I'd like to join the description column to column A where the value in A matches the prefix. I have a feeling that there is an efficient pandas one-liner for it...

We can assume that all values in `A` have the format "prefix|suffix" or "prefix". Perhaps that can speed up things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with select first values of lists and [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series`:

```
print (df1)
          A
0  Spam|One
1  Spam|Two
2       Ham
3      Eggs

print (df2)  
     description
Spam         aaa
Ham           sd
Eggs         rty

print (df2.index)
Index(['Spam', 'Ham', 'Eggs'], dtype='object')

df1['description'] = df1['A'].str.split('|').str[0].map(df2['description'])
print (df1)
          A description
0  Spam|One         aaa
1  Spam|Two         aaa
2       Ham          sd
3      Eggs         rty
```

More general solution should be [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html), with `^` for extract starting strings and `join` by `|` for regex `OR` by `df2.index`:

```
pat = '(' + '|'.join('^' + df2.index) + ')'
df1['new'] = df1['A'].str.extract(pat,expand=False).map(df2['description'])
```